# PyQt monkey patching QLineEdit.paste?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to intercept paste() for a specific edit box.  After much reading and head scratching I decided to try the big hammer and monkey patch.  This didn't work for me either.  Anyone know why?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

def myPaste():
  print("paste") # Never gets here

if __name__ == "__main__":
#    QtGui.QLineEdit.paste = myPaste # Try #1
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()    
    window.setWindowTitle("monkey")
    centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(window)

    edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(centralWidget)
#    QtGui.QLineEdit.paste = myPaste # Try #2
    edit.paste = myPaste # Try #3

    window.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
    window.show()    
    app.exec_()
```

Based on feedback..i was able to use the event filter suggestion to solve my problem.  Updated example code follows...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()    
    window.setWindowTitle("monkey")

    centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(window)
    edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(centralWidget)

    window.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def eventFilter(obj, e):
        if isinstance(obj, QtGui.QLineEdit):
            if (e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress):
                if (e.matches(QtGui.QKeySequence.Paste)):
                    obj.paste()
                    t=str(obj.text()).title() # Special handling here...uppercase each word for example
                    obj.setText(t)
                    return True
            return False
        else:
            return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(obj, e)

    window.eventFilter = eventFilter
    edit.installEventFilter(window)

    window.show()    
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't "monkey-patch" `QLineEdit.paste()` is because it's not a *virtual* function. The important thing about virtual functions is that when they are overridden, the reimplemented function will get called internally by Qt; whereas non-virtual overrides will only get called by Python code. So, since `QLinedit.paste()` isn't virtual, you will instead have to intercept all the *events* that would normally result in it being called internally by Qt.

That will mean reimplementing [QLineEdit.keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#keyPressEvent), so that you can trap the shortcuts for the [default key bindings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#details); and also [QLineEdit.contextMenuEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#contextMenuEvent), so that you can modify the default context menu. And, depending on what you're trying to do, you might also need to override the default drag-and-drop handling. (If you prefer not to use a subclass, an [event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) can be used to monitor all the relevant events).

The [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) class provides access to the system clipboard, which will allow you to intercept the text before it is pasted. Every application has a single clipboard object, which can be accessed via `QApplication.clipboard()` or `qApp.clipboard()`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do what you want you can subclass `QLineEdit` and create a method that provides the custom paste functionality that you want (`paste` method isn't virtual so if it is overriden it won't be called from Qt code). In addition you will need  an event filter to intercept the shortcut for CTRL+V. Probably you will have to filter the middle mouse button too which is also used to paste the clipboard content. From the event filter you can call your replacement of `paste` method.

You can use the following code as starting point:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class myEditor(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myEditor, self).__init__(parent)

    def myPaste(self):
        self.insert("custom text pasted! ")

class myWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.customEditor = myEditor(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.customEditor)
        self.customEditor.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        if (obj == self.customEditor):
            if (e.type() == QEvent.KeyPress):
                if (e.matches(QKeySequence.Paste)):
                    self.customEditor.myPaste()
                    return True
            return False
        else:
            return QMainWindow.eventFilter(obj, e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myWindow()
    window.show()    
    app.exec_()
```

The event filter here only takes care of the keyboard shortcut for pasting. As I said you need to consider also other sources of the paste operation.